React typewriter works differently on Mobile or Tablet and Laptop, not on devtool's screens
It perfectly works on laptop/PC also in devtools, tried with all screen sizes it works perfectly.
The working is like as the typewriter writes the from the fullstop whole string after it adjusts itself and wraps it. It works on mobile size on devtools.
But in actual phone or Tablet/iPad it displays as 3 lines as follows:

Hi I'm a Software developer proficient in
{typewriter Text}
. Lorem ipsum.

1st line wraps if in case the screen size is smaller but typewriter effect seems detached with both before and after string.
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="centeredBox">
                  {introdata.description.first}
                    <span id="typewriter" style={{ color: 'lightblue', fontWeight: 'bold',  }}>
                    <Typewriter
                    options={{
                      strings: [
                        introdata.service.first,
                        introdata.service.second,
                        introdata.service.third,
                      ],
                      autoStart: true,
                      loop: true,
                      deleteSpeed: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                  </span>
                    <span class="cursor"></span>
                    {introdata.description.second}
                  </div>
                </div>

I tried to do something like "Hi I'm a Software developer proficient in {typewriter Text}. Lorem ipsum".
In this scenario, I Separated the whole text in three parts:

Hi I'm a Software developer proficient in

{typewriter Text}

. Lorem ipsum.



I am not sure if this would work for your issue, but afaik browsers and mobile handle line-breaks and inline elements a bit differently.
You could add whiteSpace: 'nowrap' to your styles in span#typewriter
also try adding "&nbsp" after Hi I'm a Software developer proficient in and before Lorem ipsum. Like so:


 Hi I'm a Software developer proficient in&nbsp;
&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum



